# Haskell, recursive call, many arguments

Tags: haskell, recursion, iteration

I am having some trouble implementing a function that is supposed to call itself multiple times. Each time it updates it's values and improves it's accuracy. In the process it calls on other functions, but I know it works up 'till:

```
Type = [Double] 
*All lists; including type: Same, but not predetermined length. 


f0 :: Double -> [[Double]] -> [Double] -> Type -> Type
```

Typical example of function call:

```
f0 1.0 [[1.0, 0.5, 1.0], [1.0, -1.0, 1.0]] [1.0, 0.0] (initTypeLength 2)
```

What I want to do:

```
f1 :: Int -> Double -> [[Double]] -> [Double] -> Type -> Type
```

... where "Int" (i) calls for number of iterations, using f0 recursively, keeping all parameters the same except the type, which is updated.

Unsure if f0 is relevant, but in case:

```
f0 a (x:xs) (y:ys) type = f_other a xs ys
                         $ f_yet_another a x y type
```

What confuses me is where and how the arguments are to be stated.

So to sum up: Everything here is static, except the one list; "Type", which is updated every iteration. How do I call this? Im getting the feeling that it's obvious, but I just can't seem to figure it out in a way that haskell understands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is this:

```
f1 k a b c t = (iterate (f0 a b c) t) !! k
```

However, type is a keyword in Haskell, so be careful with using it as a variable name.

Also, in case you are curious as to how `iterate` works, here is an implementation:

```
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
iterate f x = x : iterate f (f x)
```